# Calling batch file from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm attempting to call a batch file in code. I run it when the program starts and then every 10 minutes ( for testing purposes ). However, when the function is called through the timer it takes about 5 minutes to process it, but when I do it through start up it only takes 30 seconds.Its copying images from point A to point B on the local computer. The amount to be copied is 400 files or so.

```
net use t: "image source" /persistent:yes
xcopy t: "c:\images" /C /Q /I /Y
net use /delete t:
```

Here is the code for the batch file.Doing net use because of problems with permissions

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\getDiscImages.bat");        
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();`       
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;        
proc.StartInfo = p;         
proc.Start();         
proc.WaitForExit();
```

This is the code in c#. It works its just a tad bit slow. Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: You should use `pushd` instead of `net use`.

Comment: @sehe: `pushd` is usually used to CD to a network share.  It will automatically map a drive if necessary (unmap with `popd`).  He can then copy `.`.

Comment: At least, you shouldn't specify `/persistent:yes`

Comment: Why not copy the files directly from C# instead of a batch file?  If this code is doing anything at all important, you'll never know if it fails inside the batch file - I wouldn't like seeing this in a production environment.  Doing the copy from C# means you can fail gracefully and correctly log the error, etc.  On the other hand, if this truly stays within a test/experimental environment, then carry on...